# JQuery Mobile Select doesn't refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I have 2 select.

```
<select name="paketart" id="paketart">
    <!--Via Jquery-->                       
</select>

<select name="terminart" id="terminart">
    <!--Via Jquery-->
</select>
```

And the Javascript code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#kundenselectid").change(function() {
        $('#terminart').empty();
        $('#paketart').empty(); 

            $.getJSON( "/Daten/GetPakete.php", {id : $('#kundenselectid').val()},function( data ) {
                var first = true;

                $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
                    if (first)
                    {
                        $('#paketart').append('<option value="' + val['geId'] + '" selected>' + val['paName'] + ' - ' + val['Rest'] + '</option>');

                        $.getJSON( "/Daten/GetTerminart.php", {id : $('#paketart').val()},function( data ) {                                    
                            $.each( data, function( key2, val2 ) {
                                $('#terminart').append('<option value="' + val2['taId'] + '">' + val2['taName'] + ' - ' + val2['taDauer'] + '</option>');
                            });             
                        });                     
                    } else {
                        $('#paketart').append('<option value="' + val['geId'] + '">' + val['paName'] + ' - ' + val['Rest'] + '</option>');
                    }
                });     
            });


        $('#terminart').selectmenu('refresh', true);
        $('#paketart').selectmenu('refresh', true); 
    });
});
```

But the Problem is it doesn't select the first option.
[image: Result]

The options are added but I cant select them.

[image: Options are added to the select]

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you add a fiddle please, not sure what value $("#kundenselectid") provides...

Comment: Did you try $(document).on("pagecreate","#page1", function(){ ... instead of $(document).ready(function() {...